# Javascript convert array to object in key, value pair format

Tags: javascript

How do I convert simple array or may be a comma separated value to object something like the one mentioned below?

```
var arry=['a','b','c','d'];
var obj=[{
            'label':'a',
            'id':'',
            'icon':''
        },
        {
            'label':'b',
            'id':'',
            'icon':''
        }, {
            'label':'c',
            'id':'',
            'icon':''
        },
        {
            'label':'d',
            'id':'',
            'icon':''
        }];
```

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] and (re)read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Showing your attempt would be helpful.

Comment: Look at the `map` array method.

Comment: I have referred to array.map and array.forEach functions, but still I have no clue on how to achieve this format. I have nill experience on javascript and failed to find any example close to this scenario.

Comment: @SoujanyaJ Please update your tried code in the question using *edit* option.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var arry=['a','b','c','d'];
var obj=[];

for (var i in arry){
    obj.push({
        'label':arry[i],
        'id':'',
        'icon':''
    });
}
```